# Windows authentication in MVC3 - how to authenticate using different domain

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory, ldap

I'm using

`<authentication mode="Windows" />`

mode in MVC intranet application. Users that will use that application are using Windows accounts from **domain A** to log in. However, the only machine (**machine X**) I can use to host my application is in **domain B**. When accessing application on **machine X** users are prompted to provide credentials from **domain B** - however they don't have accounts there, and even if they had - it's still a trouble for them to log in manually (that application was thought to ease their work). My question is: is there any way to enable authentication using **domain A** from within hosting **machine X** which is in **domain B**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That would require that trust is set up between domains A and B. If there is no trust between A and B, it's unlikely to work, unless you have matching accounts (with matching passwords) in domains A and B.

Comment: Thanks, I won't have trust - I already asked. I thought there's a chance to write a piece of code (like filter) and manually connect with domain.

Comment: If your code is executed under an account from domain A, you will still need trust between A and B to then access data in domain B. You cannot solve this by writing a piece of code...

Answer (score 0):

As was previously discussed, using integrated Windows auth, the choice is to set up a trust.

That said, if you're willing to do your own auth related stuff, some options become available. You could collect credentials in the app and then do your own thing against domain A (LDAP call, Kerb, etc.) directly against DCs in DomainB. This comes with downsides though...writing such code is not free and I've seen many folks struggle to get *all* of the nuances working just so. Also, you might lose SSO (so the user has to type their creds again). Finally, your app will now be in the business of collecting creds which has a security implication you'll have to deal with as well.

Net, I'd suggest trust first. :)